# Где должен находится файл для getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream?

Tags: java, jsp, servlet

Здравствуйте.

Возникла необходимость вынести информацию о подключениях БД в отдельный файл.
Попытался использовать такой вариант, НО не могу до сих пор понять где физически должен лежать файл `db.properties`

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
InputStream inputStream = FetchData.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/db.properties");
prop.load(inputStream);
String driver = prop.getProperty("driver");
String url = prop.getProperty("url");
String user = prop.getProperty("user");
String password = prop.getProperty("password");
```

Пробовал разместить `/web-inf/classes/db.properties`
не находит.
Пробовал указать абсолютный путь - результат также отрицательный.

Где он должен быть?

Comment: Maven? Поместите ваш файл в src\main\resources\

Comment: и уберите / из пути(т.е. грузите как `FetchData.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("db.properties")`)

Comment: Сборщик не maven, проект в IDEA. Попробовал еще 2 варианта убрать "/" + копию файла положил и в корень проекта, не получилось.

Comment: Попробуйте положить просто в `src` и опять же вызвать просто без `/`. У вас `java.lang.NullPointerException`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Пример 1. используем конструкцию `getClass().getResource("/images/logo.png")`. Поскольку имя начинается с символа '/' – оно считается абсолютным. Поиск ресурса происходит следующим образом:

К пути из classpath `c:\work\myproject\classes` приписывается имя ресурса `/images/logo.png`, в результате чего ищется файл `c:\work\myproject\classes\images\logo.png`. Если файл найден – поиск прекращается. Иначе:
В jar-файле `c:\lib\lib.jar` ищется файл `/images/logo.png`, причем поиск ведется от корня jar-файла.

Пример 2. Мы используем конструкцию `getClass().getResource("res/data.txt")`. Поскольку имя не начинается с символа '/' – оно считается относительным. Поиск ресурса происходит следующим образом:

К пути из classpath `c:\work\myproject\classes` приписывается текущий пакет класса, где находится код, – `/ru/skipy/test`, – и далее имя ресурса `res/data.txt`, в результате чего ищется файл `c:\work\myproject\classes\ru\skipy\test\res\data.txt`. Если файл найден – поиск прекращается. Иначе:
В jar-файле `c:\lib\lib.jar` ищется файл `/ru/skipy/test/res/data.txt` (имя пакета текущего класса плюс имя ресурса), причем поиск ведется от корня jar-файла.

В вашем случае нужно писать `getResourceAsStream("db.properties")` без указания  символа '/', чтобы файл нашел в папке `project\src\main\resources\`
но вы можете положить `db.properties` в `project\db.properties` и уже указать как в вашем примере

Comment: Попробовал такой еще вариант InputStream inputStream = FetchData.class.getResourceAsStream("/db.properties"); и без символа "/" ((