# Java. Как указать что app.properties лежит в папке resources?

Tags: java, io

Мне нужно считать текстовое значение переменной из файла `app.properties`, который лежит в папке `resources` я пытаюсь сделать это так:

```
private void getProp() {
        try (InputStream inputProp = new FileInputStream("app.properties")) {

            this.prop.load(inputProp);
            String a = this.prop.getProperty("serverPath");

            System.out.println(a);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Но у меня падает ошибка что файл не найден. Как мне указать что `app.properties` лежит в папке `resources` а не где-то еще. Мне нужно решить задачу именно с использованием `.properties` не просто считать текстовый файл из `resources`.

Я понимаю что нужно как-то указать `app.properties` лежит именно в `resources` но не знаю как конкретно это сделать. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: new FileInputStream("/app.properties") Может так?

Comment: `resources/app.properties` ресурсы ищутся по classpath, в resource никто специально не заглядывает, если файл в какой-то папке, то и пишите путь к файлу вместе с папкой. почитайте javadoc как загружаются ресурсы для уточнения что происходит на самом деле. Это при загрузке через getResourceAsStream, а через FileInputStream указывайте полный путь к файлу или относительно рабочей папки. http://skipy-ru.livejournal.com/5343.html

Comment: Забыли про пермишен?

Comment: ответ в этом http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/549386/%D0%93%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-getclassloader-getresourceasstream/549400#549400 вопросе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй:

`try (InputStream inputProp = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("app.properties"))`

Comment: Спасибо! Это помогло.

Answer (score 0):

Нужен полный путь к папке

```
new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/app.properties");
```

Пример здесь http://devcolibri.com/3408

Comment: Классно! И программу распространять в исходниках и для запуска использовать среду разработки! Вы понимаете, что на компьютере пользователя не будет, не должно быть никаких src?

Answer (score 0):

Обращение к файлу в каталоге `resources`, обратите внимание, что символ `/` важен тут:

```
try (InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/app.properties")) {
    Properties properties = new Properties();

    properties.load(is);

    String serverPort = properties.getProperty("server.port");
    System.out.println(serverPort);
}
```

[Подробнее про обращение к ресурсам приложения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/549386/%D0%93%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-getclassloader-getresourceasstream).