# Ошибка при перемещении класса в другой пакет

Tags: java, io

Есть метод проигрывания аудиоформата.

```
 public void soundClick(){
        try {
            clipClick = AudioSystem.getClip();
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(getClass().getResourceAsStream("click1.wav"));
            AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(input);
            clipClick.open(ais);
            clipClick.start();
            ais.close();
        } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Помилка під час програвання аудіо (1)");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Помилка під час програвання аудіо (2)");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Помилка під час програвання аудіо (3)");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Все нормально работало, до тех пор пока я не переместил класс с этим методом в другой пакет. Теперь при воспроизведении звука выдает ошибку.

```
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.getInIfOpen(BufferedInputStream.java:159)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265)
    at com.sun.media.sound.RIFFReader.read(RIFFReader.java:125)
    at com.sun.media.sound.RIFFReader.<init>(RIFFReader.java:60)
    at com.sun.media.sound.WaveFloatFileReader.internal_getAudioFileFormat(WaveFloatFileReader.java:65)
    at com.sun.media.sound.WaveFloatFileReader.getAudioFileFormat(WaveFloatFileReader.java:55)
    at com.sun.media.sound.WaveFloatFileReader.getAudioInputStream(WaveFloatFileReader.java:117)
    at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AudioSystem.java:1113)
    at com.pav.avdonin.server.Server.soundClick(Server.java:926)
    at com.pav.avdonin.server.Server$3.actionPerformed(Server.java:1096)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2237)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2295)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4889)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4526)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4467)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2281)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Почему поток закрыт?

Comment: Где находится файл click1.wav?

Comment: C:\Users\CleBo\IdeaProjects\PControler\src\main\resources

Comment: Странно, что работало до этого. Если путь к файлу не начинается с символа '/' - класс попытается его загрузить из пакета выбранного класса, т.е.в C:\Users\CleBo\IdeaProjects\PControler\src\main\java\your\packet.
Чтобы файл был загружен из resources нужно в названии файла указать /resources/click1.wav

Comment: Заработало. Но... когда указал просто /click1.wav. Если указать /resources/click1.wav - не работает. Из за чего это может быть? Я так думаю, что при компиляции все файлы из /resources попадают в корневой коталог, так же как при компляции jar файла.

Comment: Да, все верно, попадают)

Comment: @friednail, подскажите, почему многие ответы на вопрос дают в комментариях, а не ниже в ответах? какой в этом смысл?

Comment: в комментариях имеет смысл уточнить постановку вопроса, но порой бывает так, что сразу и ответ отвечается. Тогда, по хорошему, следует ответ из комментариев перенести в полноценный ответ. Что я сейчас и сделаю...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В javadoc'е к методу `Class#getResourceAsStream(String name)` описан алгоритм поиска файла, путь к которому передается в виде параметра name. Подробно этот алгоритм уже разбирали [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/549400/223703). Хоть там и рассматривался метод `getResource()`, принцип остается тот же.
В итоге, что же мы имеем: достаточно исправить путь к ресурсу.

```
InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/click1.wav"));
```