# Как создать InputStream через ClassPath?

Tags: java, classpath

Задача - считать файл WordsEx7.txt, который находится в той же папке, что и класс Ex8. Инициализировать Scanner, так, чтобы мы брали файл из classpath.
Пробовал варианты от сюда
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20389255/reading-a-resource-file-from-within-jar
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464291/how-to-really-read-text-file-from-classpath-in-java

Результат один: in = null и NullPointerException.
Пробовал изменять положение файла и передавать как аргумент ("/wordsEx7.txt). Тоже не помогло.

```
public class Ex8 {
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
    Map<String,Set<Integer>> words = new HashMap<>();
    InputStream in = Ex8.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("wordsEx7.txt");
    try(Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(in))) {
        ...
            }
            ...
        }
    }
  ...
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос обсуждался здесь: [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/549386/Где-должен-находится-файл-для-getclassloader-getresourceasstream/549400](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/549386/%D0%93%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-getclassloader-getresourceasstream/549400)

Все что вам нужно - перед именем файла поместить имя папки в которой находится класс Ex8. Т.е. если это папка "ex8", то:

```
 InputStream in = Ex8.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("ex8/wordsEx7.txt");
```

если вызов идет из папки предыдущего уровня.

Answer (score 1):

Решение сверху действительно сработает в том случае, если вы не используете Maven или Gradle. Если используете, например, Maven, то файл следует поместить по пути `src/main/resources`